# spring -> how to define schema for all beans in one place

Tags: java, spring

I have 30-40 xml  files and each file contains  schema like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
```

is  it  possible to define schema for all beans in  one place?

Comment: No. That's an XML mechanism, not a Spring mechanism. XML is not aware that you may have more than one XML file and therefore you may want to avoid duplicated parts in all of them.